# Content fade in using jquery

Tags: javascript, android

How would you go about making content fade in such as paragraphs, pics, etc. Hoping to make the contents of the page fade in as I scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [.fadeIn function](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) for this.

`$(".hiddenContent").fadeIn()`

If you would like some additional information about how this fits into your scrolling functionality then check: [Fade in div when it's scrolled into viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180375/fade-in-div-when-its-scrolled-into-viewport)